# Casting super class to sub class in Android

Tags: java, android, superclass

I've Create a class named CalendarCell that extends a TextView, i've added some instances to a TableRow inside a TableLayout, i want to loop over these instances and use some methodes inside them, but, the method " getVirtualChildAt " of TableRow returns a View, not a CalendarCell and i can't cast (obviously) from View (or TextView) ton CalendarCell

Comment: Try `view instanceof CalendarCell`

Comment: What's the (obvious) reason you can't cast?

Comment: rolled back silly and *inconsistent* 3rd-party highlighting abuse

Answer (score 1):

Since `CalendarCell` class extends `TextView` that is a subclass of `View`, you can check if the retrieved object is an instance of `CalendarCell` and then safely cast it to a `CalendarCell` instance.

```
View view = tableRow.getVirtualChildAt(i);
if (view instanceof CalendarCell) {
  CalendarCell calendarCell = (CalendarCell) view;
  // Here you can access calendarCell object
}
```